# jQuery nth item of id/class

Tags: jquery

I'd like to use the id selector:

```
$("#id")
```

Is there a way to do this to only the nth element with that ID on the page? i.e.

```
$("#id:n")
```

Comment: You must have a unique id

Comment: IDs should be unique. You can use `:eq()` to select the element at index x

Comment: Voting to reopen, because it's a very frequent error (it's possible there's an older QA which might be used, though).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There can be only ONE element with a given id in a page.

From [the HTML norm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id) :

> There must not be multiple elements in a document that have the same
>   id value.

Now suppose you want to get the nth element with a given class in your page, you may use [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) :

```
$('.myclass').eq(index)
```

Comment: Technically if you want the nth element, you select the n-1 with eq() since it's zero-based.

Comment: @j08691 Yes. I edited (please let your comment in case it's not clear for OP). In fact what is wrong isn't the code but the sentence as it's probable OP wanted in fact the element of index n.

Answer (score 6):

You can do like this:

```
$("#id:eq(n)")
```

But like @dystroy answer, it should be only 1 id in a page so you better using class.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `:eq(n)` selector fetch the n-th item, but id should be unique.

You should use the `class` attribute to group similar elements.