# How do I retrieve the nth item returned by a jquery class selector?

Tags: jquery, dom, sizzle

If I pick out a class with a jquery selector, like this: `$(".listHeading")` and it returns m elements from the DOM, how do I pick out the nth of the m elements via a selector? I found this post, but it is not quite right because it says to call `.eq()` which throws an error : [jQuery nth item of id/class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481510/jquery-nth-item-of-id-class)

Comment: What's wrong with the answer in that post?

Comment: What's the error it throws?

Answer (score 2):

Just do

```
$(".listHeading")[n]
```

the order of the returned elements is the same as the order of their appearance in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the nth element with the following code:

```
$(".listHeading").get(n-1);
```

Be careful, it won't return a jQuery object. So if you want a jQuery object, use:

```
$($(".listHeading").get(n-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".listHeading").eq(n)
```

to get a jquery object or

```
$(".listHeading")[n]
```

to get a dom element.

Answer (score 0):

To use a selector to pick the element, use the `:eq(n)` selector. It uses a zero based index, so for example to find the fourth element:

```
var el = $(".listHeading:eq(3)");
```

Comment: `:eq` docs suggest using `.eq` for performance.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: Good point, but the OP specifically asked for a way to do it with a selector.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.